# Remove period[.] and comma[,] from string if these does not occur between numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to remove comma and period from a text only when these does not occur between numbers.

So, following text should return

```
"This shirt, is very nice. It costs DKK ,.1.500,00,."

"This shirt is very nice It costs DKK 1.500,00"
```

I tried with

```
text = re.sub("(?<=[a-z])([[$],.]+)", " ", text)
```

but it does not substitute anything in the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
>>> s = "This shirt, is very nice. It costs DKK ,.1.500,00,."
>>> re.sub('(?<=\D)[.,]|[.,](?=\D)', '', s)
'This shirt is very nice It costs DKK 1.500,00'
```

Using a *positive lookbehind assertion* to check the symbols are preceded by a non digit character, and an *alternation* on the same character set using a *positive lookahead assertion* to check it is followed by a non digit character.

https://regex101.com/r/54STMM/4

Comment: Thanks. I am finding it little tricky that why the above expression does not convert u.s. to us?

Comment: Notice that you still have a problem there with the last char (a comma at the end).

Comment: And it will also not work with dot/comma as a first-char on the string.

Comment: @dekel Dropped the group, didn't notice the binding effect it had on the other assertion.