# Removing the . (full-stop) and , (commas) that occurs in-between numbers in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How to remove the . (full-stop) and , (commas) that occurs in-between numbers in python?

Example Input: "The shirt costs 1,50,0, coat costs 1.5.00, and the cap costs 2.50."

Example output: "The shirt costs 1500, coat costs 1500, and the cap costs 250."

The solution [Remove period[.] and comma[,] from string if these does not occur between numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445290/remove-period-and-comma-from-string-if-these-does-not-occur-between-number) does the inverse of the above mentioned requirement.

While, `re.sub('[.,]','',input)` removes all the commas and full-stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern

```
(\d)[,.](\d)
```

[image]

Replace by `\1\2`

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/RvXVTr/2/)

If there are numbers with multiple `. or ,` you can use lookaround

```
(?<=\d)[,.](?=\d)
```

- `(?<=\d)` - Match must be preceded by digit characters
- `[,.]` - Match `, or .`
- `(?=\d)` - Match must be followed by digit

Replace by empty string

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/RvXVTr/3/)

Comment: `re.sub('(\d)[,.](\d)','\1\2',sentence)`

Comment: doesn't quite work for the second case of `1.5.00` (but running it twice would work here)-

Comment: The second solution (?<=\d)[,.](?=\d) works perfectly.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa you can use lookarounds, see the second pattern

Comment: `re.sub('(?<=\d)[,.](?=\d)','',sentence)`

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa added further explanation for second pattern as well

Comment: @Steve we can use lookarounds too, i have added a pattern with lookaheads also